# OutOfMemoryError problems - android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, image-resizing, android-drawable

my app (memory game) is using various images. In my /drawable/ folder are about ~50 .png images with 252x252 size. My app has some levels, for example 4x3, 4x6 etc. After 3-4 games (for example, I started from 2x2 to 4x6) - my app is crashing (Unfortunately, your app has stopped). In LogCat I have these errors:

```
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:530)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:505)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:357)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:777)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:669)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:11861)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at com.example.testlogo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:145)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-16 23:05:35.382: E/AndroidRuntime(13622):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As I said, I am using images from /drawable/ folder. To make for example 4x3 level, I am using GridLayout and ImageButtons. I have a method, which randomizes ImageButton's place and then I am putting the image to the ImageButton, like this:

```
button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

For resize my ImageButton I am using:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int screenwidth = display.getWidth();
        int screenheight = display.getHeight(); 
            button.setMaxHeight(screenwidth/3);
            button.setMaxWidth(screenwidth/3);
```

So I do not really know, how to manage with my problem. Maybe should I use Bitmap instead of ImageResource?

**Note**: 
1)Every level have own class, they are very similar to each other.

2)Every level class have 24 images. If the level is 4x3 I will get first random 6 pics.

3)Every activity are using finish(); method if the activity is closed/onBackPressed.

```
int[] img ={R.drawable.cherry90,R.drawable.apple90,R.drawable.applered90,R.drawable.apricot90,R.drawable.banana90,R.drawable.blueberry90,


R.drawable.coconut90,R.drawable.gooseberry90,R.drawable.grape90,R.drawable.grapefruit90,R.drawable.kiwi90,R.drawable.lemon90,
                R.drawable.lime90,R.drawable.mandarin90,R.drawable.mango90,R.drawable.melon,R.drawable.papaya90,R.drawable.peach90,
                R.drawable.pears90,R.drawable.pineapple,R.drawable.plums90,R.drawable.pomegranate90,R.drawable.raspberry90,R.drawable.strawberry90};
```

I hope you will understand what I wanted to say. I were searching an answer to this problem, but did not find.

Comment: You probably need to increase your heap space. Check here http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/understanding-the-outofmemoryerror.html But do take note that it is a temp fix. You likely need to figure out a better way of presenting/storing your images.

Comment: Reduce the size of the images and you are done.

Comment: As it was said You should use smaller images or load scaled bitmaps depending on cell size by yourself. You can find some examples here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html .

Comment: Thank You for your comments. Firstly, I will try just to reduce the size of the images, but I want, that my buttons will fit at least for 7" tablets in portrait position.I have 2x2 level, so image should has size screenwidth/2 or screenwidth/5*2. So,  to what size I need to reduce the images? Maybe there are some information, about tablet size and picture size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it an error that indicates you have used excess of your ram memory allocations, there is nothing wrong in your code it just needs to be optimized.
Here are a few ways to do this:

- Reduce the resolution of the images, you can still stretch them to the same size, but they wont show in as much detail.
- Delete or re-use image variable space.
- If you show the same image multiple times on the screen, like with most tiled maps. only create one variable where the image is stored.

Remember variables mean ram.

Comment: How you a little bit describe about: "Delete or re-use image variable space." ?

Comment: I forgot to say that in /drawable/ folder there were also background pics in 1300x600 which had size from 600kb to 1.2mb. I deleted them and changed to another, smaller, which is only 27kb. I am not sure, but now I do not get outofmemoryerror. I need to make more tests. After it I will write if it helped.

Comment: these two links should help with the basics:
[recycle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()), 
[dev doc](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html). 

As i said reducing the resolution of the image will work, this doesn't mean you should use really small images, just not really big ones.

and note different devices have different amounts of ram, so you should still aim to make your application as efficient as possible, even if you don't get out of memory errors this will also help if you need to add more images.

Comment: I haven't used it, I would assume it is there for when it is necessary. if your application requires all that memory then use it, however if it is possible to organise your code to run without it then do that.

Comment: Ok and one more question: should I use finish(); method after all activities, which is closed/onBackPressed? Isn't it bad idea? Sorry for asking, not so strong at android.

Comment: im not sure about that tbh, oh and i found a few links that may be useful to you.
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/index.html)
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/best-performance.html)
and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html).
the official documentation should always be your first place to go with a problem in my opinion.